# Save Image Canvas in sd card Java Null pointer Exception

Tags: android

I am working on a application where i need to draw and save that as image in sd card

```
 public void onClickSave()
        {

            FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
            v.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            if (bm != null) {
                try {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                    File file = new File(path, "screentest.jpg");
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();                     
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(),1000).show();
                }
            }
```

and the function call occurs here

```
 Button btn_save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                drawView.onClickSave();

            }
        });
```

and i got the error in log as :

```
05-23 12:46:25.413: W/dalvikvm(669): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.page2.DrawView.onClickSave(DrawView.java:173)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.page2.Draw$3.onClick(Draw.java:60)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-23 12:46:25.423: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white" >
<FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/main_frame"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_weight="0.1">

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      /> 

</FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0.9" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Redo" />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:text="Undo" />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:text="Save" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>This is my xml
```

Give me some other way of storing canvas draw as image in sd card
My app force closed when i clicked Save Button please help me
Thanks In Advance

Comment: on which line you getting error ?

Comment: Can you show line DrawView.java:173 ?

Comment: 173:DrawView is function definition drawview.onClickSave()

Comment: I couldnt find which line i am getting error

Comment: the problem is in Draw. java line number 60. What do you have exactly in that line

Comment: the function call drawView.onClickSave() is in line 60 of Draw.java

Comment: FrameLayout v is null or drawView is null

Comment: i edited my post what i need to do in that frame layout i kept the drawview so it cannot be null please give some code /solution

Comment: Problem location: DrawView.java:173 or Draw.java:60. Show this lines in your code.

Comment: 173 is function definition and 60 is function call of OnclickSave() user Defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would supsect

```
       FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
```

to return **null**

Check this using a debugger or logging

When your view does not contain a FrameLayout it is either

- not created by your xml
- or "main_frame" has been deleted in an other function

if this code is really at line 173

```
  public void onClickSave()
```

than this is very suspect, because there is no access to a reference.
This may be a hint of outdating the code and the apk. Try to rebuild the project
(project->clean on eclipse)

Comment: may be frame layout returns null k i agree but what i need to do ? but i included frame layout in xml why it is returning null

Answer (score 0):

try building your drawing cache before using it:

```
v.buildDrawingCache();
```